# https vs ssl- when to use what

Tags: https

Is https different from http with ssl? If so, when should one use https and when ssl?

Comment: Please google it first. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure

Comment: Just by typing this same in the google would give you the answer.

Comment: I googled the question and got sent here :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`HTTPS` is a transfer protocol in web and it uses `SSL` in its underlying (Socket) layer. Its possible for `HTTPS` to use other technologies for achieving security for transferring `HTTP` traffic in the future.

`SSL` is a way of securing data transfer at socket layer. It could be used for other purposes (i.e `FTPS`).

Comment: No. HTTPS is simply HTTP over SSL/TLS.

Comment: Isn't it documented that HTTPS **must** use SSL and thus it is not possible for HTTPS to use other technologies for achieving security for transferring HTTP traffic in the future?

Answer (score 15):

Nope. HTTPS is HTTP over SSL.

Comment: Pretty straightforward explanation. +1